# How does netTiers pass data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .nettiers

I have generated code using netTiers. Everything works fine, but I want to do some modifications.

Eg: I have a `column[dataType varchar]` (in a table) to store imageURL. For the same netTiers generates a `TextBox`. I want to replace the `TextBox` with a `FileUpload`, save the image in a folder and insert the URL into the DB.

The problem I am facing here is that I have no clue how netTiers is passing the data. Where is the insert query? They have nothing in the button click also :O . I tried searching the button's `ID` in the entire solution, but there was not a single occurrence .

Can you guys please point me to a good article or any useful resource? I am trying to get a grip at it but it seems it's gonna take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Insert query is in Data layer in Procedure.xml
Data is passing between layers. First read documentation (no matter it is not complete) from nettiers web page. You have to understand how business, data and service layers works, and than you will understand presentation layer.
If you don't like how presentation layer is generated, you can generate it yourself, and use only business, data and service layars.